# EWS only reading my inbox

Tags: c#, soap, exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2010

I am trying to read a particular email account to find items with attachments that are unread, and have certain words in the subject.

I have the below code that works but **only reads my inbox** and *not the inbox I want to check*

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback=CertificateValidationCallBack;
    ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP2);// .Exchange2007_SP1);

    service.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
    service.AutodiscoverUrl("bbtest@domainname.com"); //, RedirectionUrlValidationCallback); //bbtest@bocuk.local

    ItemView view = new ItemView(1);

    string querystring = "HasAttachments:true Kind:email"; 
    //From:'Philip Livingstone' Subject:'ATTACHMENT TEST' Kind:email";

    // Find the first email message in the Inbox that has attachments. 
    // This results in a FindItem operation call to EWS.
    FindItemsResults<Item> results = service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, querystring, view);

    foreach (EmailMessage email in results)

        if (email.IsRead == false) // && email.HasAttachments == true
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("Found attachemnt on msg with subject: " + email.Subject);

            // Request all the attachments on the email message. 
            //This results in a GetItem operation call to EWS.
            email.Load(new PropertySet(EmailMessageSchema.Attachments));

            foreach (Attachment attachment in email.Attachments)
            {
                if (attachment is FileAttachment)
...
```

what do I have to change so that my code will read the messages in the inbox of *bbtest@domainname.com*?

Comment: @JakobChristensen : - I think you're right...I'm now onto a problem with error *The specified object was not found in the store.*

Comment: Which line of code is giving you that error?

Comment: @JakobChristensen: could this be affected by my test email account being hidden?

Comment: Maybe.  Are you getting the error during autodiscovery or when calling FindItems?

Comment: it was during FindItems, but I have had it unhidden, and I will use Network Credentials to ensure I can read the target mailbox.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default your mailbox' inbox folder will be set as root when calling *FindItems* on *ExchangeService* object. Assuming your domain account has the necessary permissions to access the other mailbox this below should do the trick. I have ommited the service creation part.

```
//creates an object that will represent the desired mailbox
Mailbox mb = new Mailbox(@"othermailbox@domain.com");

//creates a folder object that will point to inbox folder
FolderId fid = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, mb); 

//this will bind the mailbox you're looking for using your service instance
Folder inbox = Folder.Bind(service, fid);

//load items from mailbox inbox folder
if(inbox != null) 
{
    FindItemsResults<Item> items = inbox.FindItems(new ItemView(100));

    foreach(var item in items)
        Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Comment: +1 thanks for this, but I am now getting an error 'The specified object was not found in the store.' - any thoughts?

Comment: Where do you get this error? Make sure the account you are using has all the necessary permissions to access the target mailbox. I have a similiar setup in my company and believe my, the code works like a charm.

Comment: could this be affected by my test email account being hidden?

Comment: Probably yes, and I'm not sure but you can probably still connect to a hidden mailbox. You have to ask you sysadmin for **Distinguished Name** of that mailbox and use if instead of email address in _Mailbox_ constructor. Or just unhide the mailbox.